# Is $L_1 = \{w ∈ {0,1}∗ | \text{w has at least as many occurrences of (110)’s as (011)’s}\}$ regular?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

Let $L_1 = \{w ∈ \{0,1\}^∗ | \text{w has at least as many occurrences
                                  of (110)’s as (011)’s}\}$.

Let

$L_2=\{w ∈ \{0,1\}^∗ | \text{ w has at least as many occurrences
                                 of (000)’s as (111)’s}\}$.

Which one of the following is TRUE?

1. $L_1$ is regular but not $L_2$
2. $L_2$ is regular but not $L_1$
3. Both $L_2$ and $L_1$ are regular
4. Neither $L_1$ nor $L_2$ are regular

---

My attempt :

We cannot have two $110$'s in a string without a $011$ or vice verse.

let us consider the string $011011011011$
In this string, number of occurrences of $011$ are $4$ but when we see here $110$ is also occurred and the number of occurrence of $110$ is $3$. Yes, if a binary string starts with $11$, it can never have more no. of $011$ than $110$.

[image]

So we can observe here that whenever $110$ will be there string will be accepted
So with this idea we can build an automata for this. Therefore, it is regular.

But, L2 is not regular.(I guessed).

> Can you explain please, with pumping lemma or other way to prove/disprove classes of given languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate your argument about $L_1$: Any string not ending in $11$ is in $L_1$, and a string ending in $11$ is in $L_1$ iff it starts with $11$. So as a regular expression, $$L_1=(\{0,1\}^*(0|01))\mid 11\{0,1\}^*11\mid 111\mid 11\mid 1\mid \epsilon $$

$L_2$ on the other hand is not regular. Assume it is and let $n$ be its pumping length. Consider $1^n0^n\in L_2$ can be written as $uvw$ with $|uv|\le n$ (so consisting only of $1$'s) and $|v|\ge 1$ and such that among others $uv^3w\in L_2$. But that has more occurances of $111$ than of $000$.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

$L_2$ is can be easily seen to be non-regular using the Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Your automaton for $L_1$ seems to be right, so the language is regular, but it would probably need a more explicit argument that the automaton actually recognizes $L_1$ before it constitutes a proof.

I suggest annotating the states with all combinations of "last two symbols seen" and "difference between number of 110s and 001s ever seen" that can happen in that state. Then it's a purely local matter to verify that those invariants are preserved by every transition.

Comment: Thanks for beautiful explanation.